# Combining union and WHERE conditions in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

schema:

```
   BookingDependent ( BookinngID(pk,fk) , DependentID(pk,fk))
   Booking (BookingID(pk),GuestID(fk), ArriveDate,DepartDate, Totalprice)
```

SQL statement Attempted :

```
SELECT g.FORENAME, g.SURNAME       
FROM GUEST g
INNER JOIN BOOKING b ON g.GUESTID = b.GUESTID
UNION
SELECT d.FORENAME, d.SURNAME
FROM DEPENDANT d
INNER JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd ON bd.DEPENDANTID = d.DEPENDANTID
WHERE (SELECT * FROM BOOKING b
WHERE b.DEPARTDATE > '20-MAR-2013');
```

hello guys, im trying to construct an sql query which lists all guests and dependents who are staying in the hotel currently rather than display all historical guests and dependents from the database.I want to simply display all guests and dependents who are present.Im having issue from the WHERE clause where missing expression error comes up. How can i fix this ? I want to be using union too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the column that associates the `WHERE` clause filter to the rest of your query.

It seems like you want to use the following query:

```
SELECT g.FORENAME, g.SURNAME       
FROM GUEST g
INNER JOIN BOOKING b 
   ON g.GUESTID = b.GUESTID
WHERE b.DEPARTDATE > '20-MAR-2013'
UNION
SELECT d.FORENAME, d.SURNAME
FROM DEPENDANT d
INNER JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd 
   ON bd.DEPENDANTID = d.DEPENDANTID
WHERE bd.BookingID in (SELECT b.bookingid   
                       FROM BOOKING b
                       WHERE b.DEPARTDATE > '20-MAR-2013');
```

You will notice that I altered your `WHERE` clause to `WHERE bd.BookingID in ..`. This will return any rows that have a `BookingId` with the `DepartDate` that you want.